# Clean Architecture: Where to implement pagination logic?

Tags: android, mvp, clean-architecture

There is a REST API where search keyword entered by the user is used to query and get results. Sometimes, too many results are returned. I don't want to put a maximum result limit on the server side so I want to handle it on the application. In the application, I try to follow [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). I have a fragment, a presenter, a usecase and an API client. User enters a keyword, presses search button, the keyword passed to related usecase function through presenter. Usecase gets results from API client and pass results to presenter through listener. Presenter notifies fragment so that results are displayed.

I want to show max of ten pages of results. Where should I put this control? Usecase or presenter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will strictly make it ten pages ALWAYS, put it on your **usecase** because here, application business rules resides. So you don't need to pass it if your just always going to pass ten.

But, I suggest to make it as a **parameter** on the **presenter**, to make it flexible because maybe you will have a scenario in which you want to adjust the max pages on a specific `activity/fragment`.

Comment: If you place the pagination controls in the presentation layer, you will need to compute the use case result for each query. This may cause a performance issue because the use case is agnostic and returns all results for each request. A better solution may be to place pagination in the infrastructure layer and update your use case by passing the 'page' and 'page size' parameters. The domain layer still does not need to include specific pagination logic, as the pagination parameters are simply passed through to the infrastructure layer where the actual data retrieval logic is implemented.

Comment: @RobertoFerro Based on the question, it seems that the computation will still happen on the API, therefore there will be no performance issues on the domain layer regardless on where the parameters at. From what I understand, the question is where should you put the control on changing the pagination parameters, and having it on the presenter will give the benefits said above. One scenario that I'm thinking of when you must put it on usecase is when you have a different business logic that depends on the pagination parameter (eg: loading more details if it was a smaller size)

Answer (score 1):

Is pagination part of your domain? If it’s not, you might want to have a separate query interface/flow. Use the domain repository for write based operations. Load the entity, update, save. For queries have a different interface that enables query and filter operations. The user case still exists. The input still has the parameter, but your domain repository api is clean. You can even have the same database class implement your query api.